# Linux startup init.d file always fails with following bash, whats wrong?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following bash script to update to my website my current ip. It works fine stand alone, but put into a startup file, fails upon startup. I'm guessing it's a sequencing thing, but I'm not sure how to fix the sequencing, and after a few hours of googling and trying everything I can think of, I'm hoping someone can lead me in the right direction! This is what I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/sh

IP_ADDR=$(ifconfig eth0 | sed -rn 's/^.*inet addr:(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+).*$/\1/p')
wget -q -O /dev/null http://example.com/private/RPi_IP.php?send=${IP_ADDR}
```

I can't figure out what to do. I tried adding it to other startup programs even, and it fails upon startup too. I'm using a Raspberry Pi. Any ideas?

Comment: What Linux distro and/or init system are you using (OpenRC, SysVinit, Upstart, Systemd, etc.)? Also, you might have better luck asking on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: I'm using raspbian wheezy, and okay I'll try superuser if I don't get anything here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your path might not be what you expect.  You should fully-qualify any commands that you use.  Especially for programs that live in `/sbin/`

*ie*

```
/sbin/ifconfig
/usr/bin/sed
/usr/bin/wget
```

Comment: I tried this, but I'm still getting it to say it failed form some reason.

Comment: Is there a specific error message?  Perhaps this is being run before your network adapters come up.